# TestNG incompatible for Eclipse 2019-03

Tags: testng-eclipse

While trying to install TesgNG in Eclipse 2019-03 . I got TestNG message as incompatible for  Eclipse 2019-03.Is there any solution for this problem?

[image]

Comment: How is this question related to _Selenium_? Am I missing something?

Comment: TestNG is  selenium framework

Comment: Of coarse you can use use _TestNG_ without referring to _Selenium_.

Comment: Do you have solution for the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See a relevant issue: [TestNG cannot be installed on recent versions of Eclipse via Eclipse Marketplace](https://github.com/cbeust/testng-eclipse/issues/429): "TestNG Eclipse plugin is under maintained, it's stable enough so you don't see much commit activities on the repo.
Feel free to create feature request and/or issue.

closing the ticket now since the Marketplace page is getting updated, thanks @cbeust"

Comment: It seems things have improved, see [Cannot add the TextNG 7.0 library #445] (https://github.com/cbeust/testng-eclipse/issues/445) which ends with "works for me, thanks for fixing this"